# Get specific field from property

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamic365

I am new to JavaScript and Dynamics CRM.
I have following code:

```js
var analysisCode = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("rf_analysiscode").getValue()[0].entityValues;
```

As value for `analysisCode`, I get following output:

```json
{
    "rf_name":{"name":"rf_name","value":"ABC"},
    "rf_code":{"name":"rf_code","value":"ABC"},
    "createdon":{"name":"createdon","value":"24.1.2022 10.39"}
}
```

But I want to get just the rf_code. How do I retrieve that?

Comment: QQ: the snippet is having some undocumented property "entityValues" what is that ? How are you getting this working ?

Comment: You are using the `Xrm.Page` API, which is deprecated in the current version of Dynamics 365 CE. On what version are you working? What is the exact type of attribute `rf_analysiscode`? Lookup, string?

Comment: its Lookup value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
analysisCode = {
    "rf_name":{"name":"rf_name","value":"ABC"},
    "rf_code":{"name":"rf_code","value":"ABC"},
    "createdon":{"name":"createdon","value":"24.1.2022 10.39"}
};
let rf_code = analysisCode.rf_code;
console.log('rf_code : ', rf_code);
console.log('rf_code Value : ', rf_code.value);
```

If you are getting your output in String, Firstly need to parse output and then you can get any value from that json.

Try this:

```js
analysisCode = '{"rf_name":{"name":"rf_name","value":"ABC"},"rf_code":{"name":"rf_code","value":"ABC"},"createdon":{"name":"createdon","value":"24.1.2022 10.39"}}'
let rf_code = JSON.parse(analysisCode).rf_code;
console.log('rf_code : ', rf_code);
console.log('rf_code Value : ', rf_code.value);
```

Comment: @tanaz That's great! you can give up vote/Down vote for ans.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your result to JSON like this:

```
const analysisCodeObj = JSON.parse(analysisCode);
```

Get `rf_code` like this:

```
const rfCodeObj = analysisCodeObj["rf_code"];
```

Comment: You are welcome, please feel free to accept it as a solution if it helped and don't hesitate to ask me any other questions.